# How to convert nested dictionary to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I've got a nested dictionary. It's some Nasdaq kind of data. Like this:

```
{'CLSN':     
 Date        Open  High   Low  Close  Volume  Adj Close                                                
 2015-12-31  1.92  1.99  1.87   1.92   79600       1.92
 2016-01-04  1.93  1.99  1.87   1.93   39700       1.93
 2016-01-05  1.89  1.94  1.85   1.90   50200       1.90,
 'CCC':    
 Date            Open       High        Low      Close  Volume  Adj Close                                                              
 2015-12-31  17.270000  17.389999  17.120001  17.250000  177200  16.965361
 2016-01-04  17.000000  17.219999  16.600000  17.180000  371600  16.896516
 2016-01-05  17.190001  17.530001  17.059999  17.450001  417500  17.162061,
}
```

To help you understand, it's the **key** followed by the **values**, and the **values** is a **dataframe**!

Before asking, I tried the way `pd.Panel(nas)['CLSN']`, so I'm sure its value is a dataframe. But the way `pd.Panel(nas).to_frame().reset_index()` doesn't help me at all! It outputs an empty dataframe with thousands of columns which filled by the stock name.

Now it's bothering, I want a dataframe like this:

```
index  Date      Open       High       Low       Close      Volume     Adj Close                                            CLSN 2015-12-31  1.92       1.99       1.87       1.92       79600.0   1.92
CLSN 2016-01-01   NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN
ClSN 2016-01-04  1.93       1.99       1.87       1.93       39700.0   1.93  
CCC  2015-12-31  17.270000  17.389999  17.120001  17.250000  177200.0  16.965361
CCC  2016-01-04  17.000000  17.219999  16.600000  17.180000  371600.0  16.896516
CCC  2016-01-05  17.190001  17.530001  17.059999  17.450001  417500.0  17.162061
```

Surely, I can use `for` loop to get each stock's dataframe, but it kills me to join them all.

Do you have a better idea? Extremely willing to know!

---

To MaxU:
After using the method `print(nas['CLSN'].head())`, it outputs like:

```
            Open  High   Low  Close  Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                  
2015-12-31  1.92  1.99  1.87   1.92   79600       1.92
2016-01-04  1.93  1.99  1.87   1.93   39700       1.93
2016-01-05  1.89  1.94  1.85   1.90   50200       1.90
2016-01-06  1.86  1.89  1.77   1.78   62100       1.78
2016-01-07  1.75  1.80  1.75   1.77  117000       1.77
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

assuming that `Date` is an index (not a regular column):

Source dictionary:

```
In [70]: d2
Out[70]:
{'CCC':                  Open       High        Low      Close  Volume  Adj Close
 Date
 2015-12-31  17.270000  17.389999  17.120001  17.250000  177200  16.965361
 2016-01-04  17.000000  17.219999  16.600000  17.180000  371600  16.896516
 2016-01-05  17.190001  17.530001  17.059999  17.450001  417500  17.162061,
 'CLSN':             Open  High   Low  Close  Volume  Adj Close
 Date
 2015-12-31  1.92  1.99  1.87   1.92   79600       1.92
 2016-01-04  1.93  1.99  1.87   1.93   39700       1.93
 2016-01-05  1.89  1.94  1.85   1.90   50200       1.90}
```

Solution:

```
In [73]: pd.Panel(d2).swapaxes(0, 2).to_frame().reset_index(level=0).sort_index()
Out[73]:
            Date       Open       High        Low      Close    Volume  Adj Close
minor
CCC   2015-12-31  17.270000  17.389999  17.120001  17.250000  177200.0  16.965361
CCC   2016-01-04  17.000000  17.219999  16.600000  17.180000  371600.0  16.896516
CCC   2016-01-05  17.190001  17.530001  17.059999  17.450001  417500.0  17.162061
CLSN  2015-12-31   1.920000   1.990000   1.870000   1.920000   79600.0   1.920000
CLSN  2016-01-04   1.930000   1.990000   1.870000   1.930000   39700.0   1.930000
CLSN  2016-01-05   1.890000   1.940000   1.850000   1.900000   50200.0   1.900000
```

alternatively you can leave `Date` as part of your index:

```
In [74]: pd.Panel(d2).swapaxes(0, 2).to_frame().sort_index()
Out[74]:
                       Open       High        Low      Close    Volume  Adj Close
Date       minor
2015-12-31 CCC    17.270000  17.389999  17.120001  17.250000  177200.0  16.965361
           CLSN    1.920000   1.990000   1.870000   1.920000   79600.0   1.920000
2016-01-04 CCC    17.000000  17.219999  16.600000  17.180000  371600.0  16.896516
           CLSN    1.930000   1.990000   1.870000   1.930000   39700.0   1.930000
2016-01-05 CCC    17.190001  17.530001  17.059999  17.450001  417500.0  17.162061
           CLSN    1.890000   1.940000   1.850000   1.900000   50200.0   1.900000
```

---

**OLD answer** - it assumes that `Date` is a regular column (not an index)
Try this:

```
In [59]: pd.Panel(d).swapaxes(0, 2).to_frame().reset_index('major', drop=True).sort_index()
Out[59]:
            Date   Open   High    Low  Close  Volume Adj Close
minor
CCC   2015-12-31  17.27  17.39  17.12  17.25  177200   16.9654
CCC   2016-01-04     17  17.22   16.6  17.18  371600   16.8965
CCC   2016-01-05  17.19  17.53  17.06  17.45  417500   17.1621
CLSN  2015-12-31   1.92   1.99   1.87   1.92   79600      1.92
CLSN  2016-01-04   1.93   1.99   1.87   1.93   39700      1.93
CLSN  2016-01-05   1.89   1.94   1.85    1.9   50200       1.9
```

where `d` is your `nested dictionary`:

```
In [60]: d
Out[60]:
{'CCC':         Date       Open       High        Low      Close  Volume  Adj Close
 0 2015-12-31  17.270000  17.389999  17.120001  17.250000  177200  16.965361
 1 2016-01-04  17.000000  17.219999  16.600000  17.180000  371600  16.896516
 2 2016-01-05  17.190001  17.530001  17.059999  17.450001  417500  17.162061,
 'CLSN':         Date  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume  Adj Close
 0 2015-12-31  1.92  1.99  1.87   1.92   79600       1.92
 1 2016-01-04  1.93  1.99  1.87   1.93   39700       1.93
 2 2016-01-05  1.89  1.94  1.85   1.90   50200       1.90}
```

Comment: I've done as you said, but it returns an error: `KeyError: 'Level major not found'`, I hardly understand what your code means, `swapaxes(0, 2)`, and it seems I don't have a definition of `major`.

Comment: @PanKevin, you can also use `reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` instead. But it's strange because i would expect a `major` column after doing `reset_index()`...

Comment: Amazing! All it output is minor, but the column of date is missing..And it's like `minor    Open       High        Low      Close     Volume  Adj Close                                                            
A      41.900002  42.349998  41.720001  41.810001  1449300.0  41.357005
A      37.369999  37.950001  37.000000  37.689999  2666200.0  37.281641
A      37.400002  38.029999  37.400002  37.610001  1831200.0  37.202510
A      40.240002  40.990002  40.049999  40.730000  2103600.0  40.288705`  ,Could you explain it??

Comment: @PanKevin, can you [post in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43305643/edit) an output of `print(nas['CLSN'].head())`? Is it possible that your `Date` column is an index in the original DFs in the dictionary?

Comment: I‘ve posted it, and I totally agree that `Date` column is an index of the DF. Before I Posted the question, I'd done some editing on the output, If that's what confused you, I am really sorry...

Comment: My goodness! It worked out! Just like what I want:`            Date       Open       High        Low      Close     Volume  \
minor                                                                     
A     2015-12-31  41.900002  42.349998  41.720001  41.810001  1449300.0   
A     2016-02-01  37.369999  37.950001  37.000000  37.689999  2666200.0   
A     2016-01-25  37.400002  38.029999  37.400002  37.610001  1831200.0   
A     2016-01-06  40.240002  40.990002  40.049999  40.730000  2103600.0   `    Thank u @MaxU, thank u, you save my life!!!

Comment: @PanKevin, glad i could help. Thanks for accepting an answer! :-)

Comment: you're so helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps pandas.concat is what you're looking for:

```
In [8]: data = dict(A=pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=['X', 'Y']),
                    B=pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=['X', 'Y']),)

In [9]: data
Out[9]: 
{'A':    X  Y
 0  1  2
 1  3  4, 
 'B':    X  Y
 0  1  2
 1  3  4}

In [10]: pd.concat(data)
Out[10]: 
     X  Y
A 0  1  2
  1  3  4
B 0  1  2
  1  3  4
```

Comment: Thank you, but Python runs too long to output the result. I use this:`df = pd.concat(pd.Panel(nas)[k] for k in nas.keys()) ` , and it is running forever.